# Как проверить наличие ключа в LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Хочу добавлять ключи в LocalStorage, если они там отсутствуют. Как мне считывать - есть ли ключ с названием, например, "ключ" в LocalStorage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (localStorage.getItem('key') !== null) {...}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже догадался. А можно ли брать значения ключей и сохранять их в переменные как числа а не текст?

Comment: @ArtemPro Вам надо изучить что такое динамическая типизация. А так же подробно изучите преобразование и сравнение всех типов.

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел нужную информацию :)

Comment: Кстати, только заметил - в Вашем выражении после "!" Идёт 2 "=". Зачем, если оно и с 1-м "=" будет работать?

Comment: @ArtemPro Это делает код более читаемым. Иначе придётся каждый раз вспоминать про то какие типы может возвращать `getItem`, про сравнение разных типов, про то что в этом случае применяется численное преобразование, про то что `null` это исключение и он не равен ничему кроме себя самого и `undefined`. Динамическая типизация и преобразование типов это тот ещё геморрой. Настоятельно рекомендую выучить в первую очередь.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше проверять локал стораж при загрузки через домКонтентЛод, например:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
      if(localStorage.getItem('language','Eng')){
        myFunction();
        document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked=true; /* примр с чекбоксом */
      }
    });
```

Сам долго искал, а при проверки условия возвращает тру, фолс. Если локол сторож записан выполнит майФанкшин и чекбокс.